# Can anyone please explain me the what are Django modelform_factory and modelformset_factory?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Kindly explain me the what are Django `modelform_factory` and `modelformset_factory`, and how do they correlate to the Django models, forms and modelforms?
I'm a beginner to `Django` and came across these terms. Looked up on the internet but wasn't able to find any good source of information on these.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple places, where you have automatically generated forms or formsets, the most visible is admin and Generic Class Views.

Every time you are working with HTML forms do add or modify data - you should use `forms.Form`. If you are working with the model - there is `forms.ModelForm` which is build on top of the `Form` - handling automatically declaration of fields, some validations and instance save. Then on top of this you have `modelform_factory` - which is generating on-demand `ModelForm` - so it is kind of shortcut to define default `ModelForm` for your model.

Similar, `modelformset_factory` is generating `ModelFormSet` to be used with one-to-many relations.

Comment: Can you provide an example of usage of modelform_factory and modelformset_factory and how do they generate 'on-demand ModelForm'? Thank you.

Comment: @AkshatAggarwal just call it with parameters - minimum one - your model... e.g.: `MyAutoModelForm = modelform_factory(MyModel)`

Answer (score 1):

modelform_factory is a method to create forms in views , without defining form in forms.py file.